# AVAudioPlayer and NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsuserdefaults, avaudioplayer

```
[PlaySound stop];        
[PlaySound prepareToPlay];        
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"defaulttext"];
NSLog(@"%@",text);
BOOL loop = [prefs boolForKey:@"switch"];
NSLog(@" %d",loop);
do {
    [PlaySound play];
} while (loop ==YES);
```

There are two major problems I am facing with this code.

1) This is a function which is called when a button is tapped... I am allocating the audio player in this function. Whenever this function is called I called the stop function on audio player yet it does not stop and two sounds play simultaneously.

2) My defaults are not registering correctly. Both the string and bool are showing nil in console.

I haves added settings bundle in my app.

Edit: Rest of the method

```
NSUInteger selectedRow= [SoundPicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
NSString *userchoice =[self pickerView:SoundPicker titleForRow:selectedRow forComponent:0];
NSString *soundpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:userchoice ofType:@"wav"];
NSURL *fileURl = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:soundpath];
NSError **error = nil;
PlayFartSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURl error:error];
```

I have sorted the problem of audio player.
Can anyone please help on `NSUserDefaults`.

In my settings root plist I have a text field with identifier name `name_preference` so I put this in code:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

text = [defaults stringForKey:@"name_preference"];
NSLog(@"%@ abc",text);
```

The log is `(null) abc` ? [I have set the default value to `hello` in plist]

Comment: Show us the rest of that method please.

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting the default values in your NSUserDefaults? You say you've got the defaults in a plist, but when do you load that plist into NSUserDefaults?

To set the default NSUserDefaults values, you need to call this somewhere early in your program, ideally in somewhere like applicationDidFinishLaunching

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaults];
```

Where 'defaults' is a dictionary of default settings, possibly loaded from a plist.